# PhantomJS scroll to capture fragment identifier

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm attempting to use PhantomJS to render screen shots - which is fine. However, some of the URLs I'm using have a fragment identifier (eg `http://blahblah.com/blahpage.html#item20`). I'd like to scroll to the top of the fragment identifier, as it does when you open the URL up in a real browser. Is there a way to do this natively with PhantomJS?

I'm using a pretty standard PhantomJS rendering process (`page.open`, `page.render`, etc) but it seems to just ignore the fragment identifier and give a screen shot of the entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhantomJS' [`page.render`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html) usually only renders the complete page, but if [`page.clipRect`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/clip-rect.html) is set, it will honor the rectange and use it for rendering. The problem is of course to determine the values for the rectangle.

You can use CasperJS' [`casper.captureSelector`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#captureselector) to render the page according to the hash:

```
casper.captureSelector("page.png", casper.evaluate(function(){
    // the good thing is that this is already a CSS selector: "#id"
    return window.location.hash;
}));
```

CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS. You can of course write your own [`getElementBounds`](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/modules/casper.js#L1029) function.